# jsp servlet embedded jetty sample code

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, jetty

I am newbie with jsp, servlet and embedded jetty I am wondering if there is a good example or a step by step tutorial I am follow to understand how this works, I have tried for 2 whole days without being able to figure this one out.

Well I have tried to figure out servlets and jsp using tomcat and I have been able to figure it out. But Tomcat is not an option because I need a very light weight interface to get things working.

I need to create a simple form , which will take input from the user and redirect to another page depending on the input.

Any pointers links for a beginner will be very helpful

I will probably create another question because I have obtained some pointers below to start creating the web interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi bhavs,**

I for  newbie with jsp, servlet and embedded jetty I found a good tutorial as link http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis330/jetty.html

or eclipse wiki http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Regards,
Tomz

Comment: with code examples here: http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded

Comment: @tomz  thanks for the code samples, helped me to get started but I am stuck at another position now, I will create another question for the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want?  Development on Jetty or Live on Jetty

For dev.
Just install Netbeans and New Maven Project -> Web Application
edit pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.14</version>
  <configuration>
   <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Done! you can write jsp & servet and test on jetty

For Live! 
You should not run jetty standalone. One popular way is run with Apache
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache

Comment: I am actually developing on embedded jetty on the eclipse IDE, I am not using the maven plugin, i have added the jetty.jar and the servlet-api.jar file into the class path of the project and I need to create a simple interface which can have many handlers depending on the input from the user.